# What is the difference between "ls" and "ls -p"?

Tags: command-line, ls

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the `ls` and `ls -p` commands in Linux?

Comment: Did you try it? did you read the manual page (`man ls`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-p` option adds a `/` at the end of directories, it helps you easily detect which one of the outputs is a directory and which one is a file.

A similar option to `-p` is `-F` which uses these characters to indicate:

- `/` --> directories
- `@` --> symbolic links
- `|` --> fifo files (named pipes).

On the other hand, `ls` does not do any of these.

These options are useful when you don't use an option like `--color` or your terminal does not support colorizing the output.

---

```
$ ls
block   dm-1    hwrng
```

It's hard to tell which one is a directory and which one is a file, right? So:

```
$ ls -p
block/   dm-1    hwrng
```

Now I can tell the `block` is a directory.

Comment: I am using cygwin64 on windows and it shows both commands as same.

Comment: @gurupalsingh what is the output of `alias ls` command?

Comment: You can also run `""ls` or `command ls` to make sure `ls` is being run without any other options, I don't know if it's going to work on `cygwin64` or not. but give it a shot.

Comment: @gurupalsingh If you are using cygwin, you shouldn't be asking questions on Ubuntu site. We only deal with Ubuntu tools and any difference in behavior of those tools isn't really relevant to this site. There is unix.stackexchange.com where cygwin is welcome.

Comment: but it comes with linux commands (in-built).... right ?

Answer (score 4):

`ls -p` adds a `/` after folder names, `ls` doesn't.

Comment: sorry but i can see that both commands does the same, i mean both commands adds the slash after folder names. I am using cygwin64 in windows.

Comment: @gurupalsingh - The output may look the same on cygwin, but that is the difference. You can also run bash on windows - https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/30/ubuntu-on-windows-the-ubuntu-userspace-for-windows-developers/

Comment: but why not on cygwin , this is my concern, nothing else. Now don't ask me to ask the developer who develop cygwin64  #lol

Answer (score 1):

From `man ls` (Which has documentation of all Linux commands)

**ls**

```
   ls - list directory contents
```

**ls -p**

```
   -p, --indicator-style=slash
          append / indicator to directories
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you don't notice the effect of `-p`, you should check what `ls` is aliased to.

As others have said, `ls -p` causes directory names to be shown with a trailing `/`. However, sometimes people ask about what flags like `-p` and `-F` do because they may appear to have no effect.

Typically the effect is clearly apparent:

```
ek@Io:~/tmp$ ls
directory  regular-file
ek@Io:~/tmp$ ls -p
directory/  regular-file
```

However, it is common for users to have a shell alias `ls` that adds options. **If one of those options is `-p` or another option that adds the trailing slash to directory names**, then adding `-p` yourself won't make any difference.

In Ubuntu, `type ls` usually shows `` ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto' ``. (This alias is provided by `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` in the user's `.bashrc` file, which is copied from `/etc/skel` when the user account is created.) When a user runs `ls` on an interactive shell prompt, it is replaced by `ls --color=auto`.

If `-p` appears to have no effect when you pass it to `ls`, try running `type ls` or `alias ls`. (Since it is possible, though rare, to have a shell function for `ls`, `type` is more reliable than `alias` at figuring out what is going on here.) It may reveal that you have an `ls` alias that includes `-p`, `--indicator-style=slash`, `-F`, or `--classify`.

There are a few ways to bypass alias expansion:

```bash
command ls
\ls
/bin/ls
```

<sup>That third command is only equivalent if the `ls` executable is `/bin/ls`. That is almost always the case; it would only be different if a second `ls` executable were added elsewhere. Run `type -a ls` to see.</sup>